# NoReverseMatch at / UpdateView

Tags: python, django

I try to use an updateview with a form. I get the error:

```
 Reverse for 'response' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s)
tried: ['app/response/(?P<pk>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

views.py:

```
class ResponseUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Model
    fields = ['response']
```

urls.py

```
path( route='response/<slug:pk>/', view=views.ResponseUpdateView.as_view(), name='response' )
```

template:

```
   {% extends "base.html" %}     
   {% load crispy_forms_tags %}     
   {% block title %}{% endblock %}     
   {% block content %}
    
   <form method="post" action="{% url 'tower:response' slug %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form|crispy }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>   </form>
    
    
    {% endblock %}
```

the error is in the template {% url 'app:response' pk %} specifically pk, I have tried using:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResponseUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['slug'] = self.kwargs['pk']
```

together with `{% url 'app:response' slug %}`

If I don't add the url everything works fine

Comment: you need to pass slug pk **{% url 'app:response' pk='your-slug' %}**

Comment: Could not parse the remainder: '=' from '='

Comment: are you trying to update the form ???

Comment: Yes I'm trying to update the value 'response' in the form. It works like this in my createview. 
I have no value for pk only thing that's in my html is extends base and block content

Comment: @DedicatedDreamer issue is in **tower/rsp** view, can show full template code

Comment: You are overriding `get_context_data` but not returning anything.

Comment: Have you made the primary key a slug field?! This is confusing because typically you'd see an ID field for PK and a separate slug field if you use slugs. So I'd expect the path to be `response/<int:pk>/` or `response/<slug:slug>/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply forgot to return the context. The following should work:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ResponseUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['slug'] = self.kwargs['pk']
        return context
```